# AES-256 decryption algorithm not working correctly

Tags: javascript, cryptography

I need to populate a database with 100 users using aes-256 encryption for passwords. Then I use the decryption method to decrypt the password and return it. All this is needed in order to measure the time how fast the selection works without encryption, with AES encryption, and with Blowfish encryption (with it later). An error occurs in the decryption method: `Error decrypting passwords error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length`

Here is my encryption code:

```
const secretKey = crypto.randomBytes(32);
const secretIV = crypto.randomBytes(16);
const insertEncryptAESUsers = async() => {
    try {
        const client = await pool.connect();
        await client.query(`TRUNCATE users_aes RESTART IDENTITY`);
        const insertUserQuery = 'INSERT INTO users_aes (username, password) VALUES ($1, $2)';

        for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            const username = faker.internet.userName();
            const password = faker.internet.password();
            const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', secretKey, secretIV);
            let encryptedPassword = cipher.update(password, 'utf8', 'binary');
            encryptedPassword += cipher.final('binary');
            encryptedPassword = Buffer.from(encryptedPassword, 'binary').toString('base64');

            await client.query(insertUserQuery, [username, encryptedPassword]);

        }
        console.log('Users AES table filled successfully');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error filling users AES table', err.message);
    }
}
```

Here is my decryption code:

```
const getUsersDecryptPasswordAES = async data => {
    try {
        const client = await pool.connect();
        const selectUsersQuery = 'SELECT username, password FROM users_aes';

        const queryResult = await client.query(selectUsersQuery);
        const passwords = queryResult.rows.map(row => row.password);


        for (let i = 0; i < passwords.length; i++) {
            const encryptedPassword = passwords[i];
            const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', secretKey, Buffer.from(secretIV, 'base64'));
            let decryptedPassword = decipher.update(Buffer.from(encryptedPassword, 'base64'), 'binary', 'utf8');
            decryptedPassword += decipher.final('utf8');

            console.log(`User ${queryResult.rows[i].username} has password: ${decryptedPassword}`);
        }

        console.log('Password decryption successful');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error decrypting passwords', err.message);
    }
}
```

how can i fix the error?

Comment: Encryption/decryption looks OK. Have you checked if decryption uses the same key and IV as encryption and if the ciphertexts have changed between saving and loading?

Comment: But inefficient (which however is not the cause of the problem): For example, it is not necessary to binary-encode the ciphertext, then load it into a buffer and Base64-encode its contents. Instead, the ciphertext can be Base64 encoded directly.

Comment: Yes, they are declared to me. And I convert it to binary in order to store it in a table with the bytea type. I still can't figure out the error...

Comment: The pure encryption/decryption work, s. online https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/FAU, i.e. for you, key and/or IV and/or ciphertext are probably inconsistent in some way (corrupted, key does not belong to ciphertext etc). Log the data, maybe you will get further.